# Sending build context to docker daemon becomes greater than 250 gb for android

Tags: android, docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration

I am trying to build a docker image for android, below is my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
LABEL maintainer="Javier Santos"

ENV VERSION_SDK_TOOLS "4333796"

ENV ANDROID_HOME "/sdk"
ENV PATH "$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools"
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'

RUN apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends \
      bzip2 \
      curl \
      git-core \
      html2text \
      openjdk-8-jdk \
      libc6-i386 \
      lib32stdc++6 \
      lib32gcc1 \
      lib32ncurses5 \
      lib32z1 \
      unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN rm -f /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts; \
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure

RUN curl -s https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${VERSION_SDK_TOOLS}.zip > /sdk.zip && \
    unzip /sdk.zip -d /sdk && \
    rm -v /sdk.zip

RUN mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/ \
  && echo "8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55\nd56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e" > $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license \
  && echo "84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license
  
RUN yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"

ADD packages.txt /sdk
RUN mkdir -p /root/.android && \
  touch /root/.android/repositories.cfg && \
  ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update 

RUN while read -r package; do PACKAGES="${PACKAGES}${package} "; done < /sdk/packages.txt && \
    ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager ${PACKAGES}
```

But when I am building this, then Sending build context to Docker daemon is getting larger from 250GB and still increasing, Is this normal, or I am doing something wrong, please suggest, thanks in advance

I have taken reference from this link https://hub.docker.com/r/javiersantos/android-ci

Answer (score 0):

The build context is not inside your Dockerfile, it's the path passed at the end of the build command, often a `.` to indicate the current directory. When building with compose it defaults to the current directory. So if this is growing, you have files in that context directory that are growing between builds.

With buildkit, this behavior changes, only sending the requested files rather than the full context. You can enable that by running `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` in the shell that runs the `docker build` command. You can also default this feature to enabled by setting the following in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and then reloading the docker engine (often `systemctl reload docker`):

```
{
  "features": {"buildkit": true }
}
```

Considering your build only adds a single file, probably the best option is to configure a `.dockerignore` in the root of your context (the same folder with the `packages.txt` file) with the following:

```
*
!packages.txt
```

The `*` ignores everything, and the `!packages.txt` reincludes that file back into the context.